# Get first value of column with condition when group by use spark dataframe

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

First im sorry if my English is not good. I beginner in spark. I have a dataframe 'raw':

```
+------------------------+----+------------------------+---+------+
|id                      |name|phone                   |sex|source|
+------------------------+----+------------------------+---+------+
|gEzIl5K+6n6GPLD0pAQKFA==|alex|na                      |M  |1     |
|gEzIl5K+6n6GPLD0pAQKFA==|alex|+Uy8Ol77OWiSuuapn5FOUg==|na |2     |
+------------------------+----+------------------------+---+------+
```

'na': string default value
source: priority, 1 > 2

And I expect result:

```
+------------------------+----+------------------------+---+------+
|id                      |name|phone                   |sex|source|
+------------------------+----+------------------------+---+------+
|gEzIl5K+6n6GPLD0pAQKFA==|alex|+Uy8Ol77OWiSuuapn5FOUg==|M  |1     |
+------------------------+----+------------------------+---+------+
```

I tried:

```
val rs = raw.orderBy(source)
        .groupBy(col("id"))
        .agg(first(when(col("phone") === "na" || col("phone") === ""
      , col("phone"))).as("phone")
        , first(when(col("sex") === "na" || col("sex") === ""
      , col("sex"))).as("sex")
        , first(when(col("source") === "na" || col("source") === ""
      , col("source"))).as("source")
)
```

but not true. Hope to get help from you guys. Great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this.

```
df.orderBy("source")
  .groupBy(col("id"))
  .agg(min(when(!'phone.isin("na",""), 'phone)).as("phone"),
    min(when(!'sex.isin("na",""),'sex)).as("sex"),
    min(when(!'source.isin("na",""), 'source)).as("source"))
  .show()

+--------------------+--------------------+---+------+
|                  id|               phone|sex|source|
+--------------------+--------------------+---+------+
|gEzIl5K+6n6GPLD0p...|+Uy8Ol77OWiSuuapn...|  M|     1|
+--------------------+--------------------+---+------+
```